# Eclipse XML Editor not working

Tags: android, eclipse-juno

[image: a screen shot of the problem]

I have been trying to fix this for a long time. I want to search through stackoverflow, but I can't find any solutions through research. Also, I have downloaded almost everything in the sdk manager, and changed the API level its rendering at. It starts rendering at 4.2 at first. [image: this is all the stuff installed in the sdk am i missing something]

Answer (score 2):

change apptheme may be it is working.

Comment: I dont Have a Themes set I dont think

Comment: Another wierd thing it does any time i make a change in the xml code I have to clean the project because theres some error

Comment: hello BRK it is sometimes eclipse packages issues because some file conflict eclipse so please change eclipse otherwise update it

Comment: this is what happened when i updated so how do you change eclipse or do you mean change to another type of eclipse